# error tokenizing with nltk from array data in file excel sequence item 0: expected str instance, list found

Tags: python, nltk, tokenize

I have a problem in this code, maybe anybody help, the data train['hadis'] from the text in excel, was success showing

```py
train['hadis'] = train['hadis'].apply(lambda x: " ".join([nltk.tokenize.word_tokenize(x) for x in x.split()]))
train['hadis'].head()
```

> TypeError: sequence item 0: expected str instance, list found

result for tokenizing every each row data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of

```
lambda x: " ".join([nltk.tokenize.word_tokenize(x) for x in x.split()])
```

Use

```
lambda x: " ".join(nltk.tokenize.word_tokenize(x))
```

Comment: can you help add for calculating words after tokenizing success, but keep in code which I asked this reference code tokens = nltk.tokenize.word_tokenize(kalimat)
kemunculan = nltk.FreqDist(tokens)
print(kemunculan.most_common())

Comment: @HendroPrasetyo that's a different question, I believe you should post a new question along with a [mcve] for that :)